# How to read XML file and pass to setText as String with all tags and white-characters [Android]

Tags: android, xml, readfile, settext

I want to read XML file, save it as String and pass to setText. I don't want to parse it but see it on my smartphone screen with all tags and white-characters, eg.

```
<a>
  <b>some text</b>
</a>
```

not:

```
some text
```

How to do it?

Comment: Do you intend to read whole file or just a part of it?

Comment: I want to read whole file.

Comment: Have you ever searched "how to read file Android/Java"?

Comment: Code for reading a -text- file in a String has been posted many times on this site. The String then can be displayed in a TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, this is how I solve my problem:

```html
    public String readXML() {

        String line;
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            InputStream is = activity.getAssets().open("subjects.xml");

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            total = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return total.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FileInputStream` to read file:

```
File file = new File(<FilePath>);
if (!file.exists()) {
  System.out.println("File does not exist.");
  return;
}
if (!(file.isFile() && file.canRead())) {
  System.out.println(file.getName() + " cannot be read from.");
  return;
}
try {
  FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
  char current;
  while (stream.available() > 0) {
    current = (char) stream.read();
    //Do something with character
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If the file does not exist then why are you still going to read it?

Comment: Where should I put my .xml file?

Comment: Put your xml file inside assets folder. `Android` exposes APIs for reading file from assets folder through `getAssetsmanager`

Comment: I'm still getting Resources$NotFoundException. Mayby because I'm doing it from Fragment class.

Comment: @greenapps: Part of this code will still be used. Reading from an assets file will output a stream and then this stream will be used to read either line by line or char by char. OP didn't provide full details at the beginning and had just asked on reading a xml file :)

Comment: @AgataPaul: Clean and build the project. May be the assets folder is not updated in project hierarchy

Comment: I've get rid of that error but app is returning empty string.

Comment: You may need to debug the code to see whats going wrong